# not able to authenticate user

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

def Login(request):

```
if request.method == "POST" :
    username1=request.POST['usernm']
    password1=request.POST['passwd']
    user=authenticate( username=username1 , password=password1)
    
    if user is not None:

        login(request, user)
        return render(request,'loginsuccess.html')

    else:

        return render(request,'login.html')
```

model.py

class My_User(models.Model):

```
first_name=models.CharField(max_length=70,primary_key=True)
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=70)
mail=models.EmailField()
username=models.CharField(max_length=70)
password=models.IntegerField(max_length=60)
```

html form

```
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    username =<input type="text" name="usernm" id="usernm" ><br>
    
    password =<input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" ><br>

    <button type="submit" > Login </button>

</form>
```

here i am not able to authenticate data i don't know whats the issue i am facing here, i am getting the user in the views as none because of which i am not able to login

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the issue you're having: could you post any errors in the console you may have while trying to use this code?

Comment: Your user model should likely be extending the Django user if you want to use authenticate.  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project and be sure to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I am not having any error while typing it is just that due to some issue i don't know what's the issue but acc to code user=authenticate(username=username1, password=password1) is supposed to return some value but it ia returning none and this executing while part.so when i hit Login page and enter usrname and password it is sent in to Login function but user is returning none value and it ia not comparing username and username1.